# Getting request headers in the same order they are received in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Is there any way in a Flask-based application of getting the request headers in the same order they are got (i.e. as `nc` for instance would show them)?

Currently I'm using `request.headers.keys()` (being `request` the incoming request object) but it doesn't guarantees the order.

I know that the order or the headers doesn't matter in HTTP but I'm wondering if this could be done anyway. For instance, to implement a logger tool for HTTP applications which prints the exact request it receives (similar to `nc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are correct in that the ordering is not guaranteed, but is dependent on the order supplied by the WSGI server in the WSGI environ dict and may vary depending on the server used.

If you can validate and fix the python version at 3.7+ and the version of the WSGI server used this may be good enough but is not necessarily portable across all servers or future versions of servers.

For example, using Flask 1.0.2 and Python 3.7.1 here, where [dict's maintain insertion order](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/) as an official part of the language spec, and Flask inserts headers into request.headers in order they are found in the environ, it can be shown by comparing the browser raw request/response headers with the output of the following Flask app that the headers maintain a 1:1 ordering match with both the internal Flask server and gunicorn 19.5.0.

Note: the form is there just to make it trivial to test get and post to see if content-type and content-length are handled differently during a POST.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return "<br>".join(list(map(lambda i: f"{i[0]}: {i[1]}", request.headers.items()))) + """
    <p><form method="POST"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form></p>"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Output:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 13
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```